# Select query using ILIKE with the IN Statement

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I want to Query 3 columns for one string value but not be case sensitive.  This is query I have started with.  How do I use the ILIKE statement with below query?

```
SELECT * FROM poles WHERE 'Century Link' IN (attach1, attach2, attach3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ANY` operator on an array:

```
SELECT *
FROM poles
WHERE 'Century Link' ILIKE ANY (array[attach1, attach2, attach3]);
```